# Как как выполнить событие с keyPressEvent один раз

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, keypressevent, qevent

Запускается скрипт. При нажатие на **`Q`** будет выводиться текст. 
Моя задача сделать так, чтобы при повторном нажатие на **`Q`**, текст не выводился, другими словами, эта функция больше не работала.

```
...
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.close()

        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Q:
            print('apple')

...
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать.  Когда потом? При повторном нажатие на что? Какой код не должен работал?

Comment: Запускается скрипт. При нажатие на Q будет выводиться текст. Моя задача сделать так, чтобы при повторном нажатие на Q, текст не выводился, другими словами, эта функция больше не работала

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пожалуйста, ВСЕГДА предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример.

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.flag = True

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.close()

        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Q and self.flag:
            print('apple')
            self.flag = False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: а если нужно выключить все клавиши и Escape в том числе ?

Comment: @KostyaKhmylov вы спросили, я вам ответил. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour Если у вас есть другие вопросы - задайте новый вопрос.